Infinite runtime or timeout in SQL SELECT queries
I'm experiencing unexpected behavior when trying to run a PostgreSQL SELECT` query. When I run it, the execution time takes about half a minute, but sometimes it doesn't stop at all
SELECT id, creation_date, first_name, last_name, domains 
FROM api.filter_users('85') as searchedUsers(id text, first_name text, last_name text, creation_date bigint) 
LEFT JOIN api.domain_aggregation_view 
ON id = user_id 
WHERE (creation_date BETWEEN 0 AND 1728306773664) AND (domains && '{CAT}')

If I run the SELECT without any conditions, it only takes a few milliseconds. Even when I run the query with just one condition (either the first part or the second part of the AND), it only takes a few milliseconds. But when I include both parts of the condition together (as written above), it causes a problem.
api.domain_aggregation_view is view:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW api.domain_aggregation_view AS
SELECT user_id, array_agg(domain) AS domains 
FROM api.user_domains
GROUP BY user_id;

api.filter_users_by_search_with_extra function receives a search_value and uses Text Search Types (tsvector, tsquery) to perform a full-text search in the api.users table. When I run the function with the search value '85', it takes only a few milliseconds.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.filter_users_by_search_with_extra(search_value text, extra_details boolean default false)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
    query TSQUERY;
    select_query text;
BEGIN 
    IF extra_details = true THEN 
        select_query := 'SELECT * FROM api.users';
    ELSE 
        select_query := 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name, creation_date FROM api.users';
    END IF;

    IF search_value = '' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE select_query;
    ELSIF search_value SIMILAR TO '%("|\\|/|'')%' THEN
        SELECT plainto_tsquery(search_value) INTO query;
    ELSE
        SELECT to_tsquery('simple', regexp_replace(plainto_tsquery('simple', search_value)::text, E'(\'[\\w-]+\')', E'\\1:*', 'g')) INTO query;
    END IF; 

    -- Extend the query to include full-text search with LATERAL join
    select_query := select_query || 
        ' LATERAL (SELECT to_tsvector(''simple'', coalesce(users.first_name, '''')) || ' ||
        ' to_tsvector(''simple'', coalesce(users.last_name, ''''))) AS ts(textsearch) ' ||
        ' WHERE $1 @@ ts.textsearch';

    -- Execute the constructed query with the tsquery
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE select_query USING query;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL STABLE;

The api.users table:
CREATE TABLE api.users(
    id text PRIMARY KEY COLLATE "numeric",
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    creation_date bigint DEFAULT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW()) * 1000)
);

The api.user_domains table:
CREATE TABLE api.user_domains(
    user_id text,
    domain text,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES api.users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, domain)
);

The result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) :

I don't have indexes.
I managed to solve it with some solutions, but I don't understand how the solution works:

I added ORDER BY id after the WHERE clause.
I converted the numbers I wrote to numeric (like 1728306773664::numeric) instead of using bigint, which is how the creation_date column works.
I didn't use the api.filter_users_by_search_with_extra('85') function and instead used the api.users table without an appropriate filter for search_value.

I would appreciate help and explanations about why any of these solutions might be helpful. I asked ChatGPT about this, but it simply explained in a very vague way that any of the solutions could lead to a general performance improvement in the SELECT statement, without explaining why my SELECT reaches such an extreme state.

Post the execution plan as text. It's not surprising that execution is so complex though. That function generates dynamic SQL, executes it and then returns the results. Only then can the outer query start joining those intermediate, unindexed results. Just because you can write such a function doesn't mean you should

Post the actual SQL generated by that function. You should post and test the final query to see what it does and what the execution plan is. I suspect the actual query prevents the database from using indexes, forcing it to compare every row with every other row. Given that the actual query is unknown at first, the database probably has to aggregate all rows in api.user_domains before performing the JOIN

Or worse, it may have to execute it once for every row produced by the dynamic query. It's hard to tell when the execution plan is an image that can't be searched.

I guess that the function returns more than the 1944 rows that EXPLAIN estimates, so the inner loop of the nested loop join is executed very often.
If that is the case, tell the optimizer that the function returns many rows:
ALTER FUNCTION api.filter_users_by_search_with_extra(text, boolean)
   ROWS 100000;

Then the optimizer can work with a better estimate and might avoid a nested loop join.
Another possibility is that the function itself is very expensive. You can easily tell if that is the case by running just the function. If that is the case, investigate the statements insode the function.
